# Openpyxl wrong max_row and max_cols

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to parse this specific [.xlsx file](https://github.com/floatingpurr/covid-19_sorveglianza_integrata_italia/files/6625176/bad_data.xlsx)

The problem is that after selecting any sheet, I cannot interate over the rows. E.g., this piece of commonly-working code:

```
wb = load_workbook('<file_path>', read_only=True)
sh = wb.worksheets[4]
for r in sheet.rows:
    print(r)
```

prints just one row reference instead of ~500. Other weird stuff:

```
wb.worksheets[4].max_row    # returns 1 instead of ~500
wb.worksheets[4].max_column # returns 1 instead of 3
```

This code has ever worked so far. It looks like there is a problem during the parsing of this specific file.

Any clues about why it happens (e.g., bad file format) and how to prevent that?

Comment: Please provide more code, especially how you load the workbook.

Comment: I added the full code that I use to reproduce the problem

Comment: The problem is that read-only mode relies on a declaration of the size at the top of the worksheet to be correct, which it obviously isn't in your case: blame the application that created the file. See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html#worksheet-dimensions

Comment: Yes, I think that the problem is the way the application created the file. Any workarounds in this cases?

Answer (score 1):

1. I tried to open your file in Excel, I tried to save it I got an error warning. I had to save it as a new copy.
2. Then I was able to open it with openpyxl.
3. Note that you can refer to the worksheet by name:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("bad_data.xlsx")
ws = wb['casi_inizio_sintomi_sint'] #grab it by name
ws.max_row
>>>500
ws.min_row
>>>1
```

I then tried your for loop, it worked well.

Comment: Oh, did you find a problem in the original file? What kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I try to open the file not in read_only mode:

```
wb = load_workbook('<file_path>')
```

I get: **There is no item named 'xl/drawings/drawing1.xml' in the archive**. This problem is described here: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1611 and it is introduced by the application that created the file, as pointed out in comments to this question.

To fix, just call `reset_dimensions()` on the worksheet and then you can finally iterate over its data:

```
for r in sheet.rows:
    print(r)
```